# Microsoft Visual Basic Run-Time error 91

Tags: vba, excel

When it get to Cells.Find it gives a Run-Time error '91'
"Object variable or With block variable not set".

```
Sub find_highlight()

w = "12:00:00 AM"

Cells.Find(What:=(w), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False).Activate
 Range("B:B").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .ColorIndex = 6
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Always use `Option Explicit` in your modules and declare all variable types
2. Always qualify objects with variables
3. Work directly with the objects (avoid `.Select` or `.Activate`)
4. Your syntax is off in your `Find` call. There is no need to wrap the variable `w` in parenthesis.

(1 through 3 are *best* practices, but not required. Leaving things out can produce unexpected results).

```
Option Explicit

Sub find_highlight()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet4") 'change as needed

Dim w As String 'maybe Date?
w = "12:00:00 AM"

Dim rng As Range, sFA  As String, rngFull As Range

Set rng = ws.Cells.Find(What:=w, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
           LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
           MatchCase:=False)

sFA = rng.Address

Do 'load all cells where w exists into range

    If Not rng Is Nothing And rngFull Is Nothing Then
        Set rngFull = rng
    ElseIf Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Set rngFull = Union(rng, rngFull)
    End If

    Set rng = ws.Cells.FindNext(rng)

Loop Until rng Is Nothing Or rng.Address = sFA

'highlight all cells found
With rngFull.Interior
    .ColorIndex = 6
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End With

rngFull.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy" 'format as date -> change as needed


End Sub
```

Comment: Nice tips, I've found that by abiding by your first three tips, you learn a lot more about VBA and how to use it than if you didn't use `Option Explicit` or avoid `.Select`.

Comment: Well said @BruceWayne. :)

Comment: Is this only spouse to highlight one cell or all cells? Meaning when i run the macro is just selects one of the 12:00:00 AM cells not all

Comment: Yes, it only does 1. Do you need it to select all cells with 12:00:00 AM? and highlight them?

Comment: Yes what do I need to change - and is there a way to format the cell to a date after it find the cell(s)